# typescript: get path of a folder

Tags: typescript

how to get folder on typescript:

i have this structure:

- src

  - infra [folder]

    - knex [folder]

      - migrations [folder]
  - config [folder]

  -knexfile.ts [file]

Hello i am currently i have the file: knexfile which is in my src / config / knexfile.ts folder
and I would like to take the src / infra / knex / migrations directory

my knexfile.ts:

```
import knex from 'knex';
import path from 'path';
import dotenv from 'dotenv';
dotenv.config();
interface KnexConfig {
  [key: string]: object;
}
const extension =
  process.env.NODE_ENV === 'production' ||
  process.env.NODE_CONFIG_ENV === 'staging'
    ? 'js'
    : 'ts';
const database: KnexConfig = {
  development: {
    client: 'postgresql',
    connection: {
      port: process.env.DB_PORT,
      host: process.env.DB_HOST,
      user: process.env.DB_USER,
      password: process.env.DB_PASS,
      database: process.env.DB_NAME,
    },
    pool: {
      min: 2,
      max: 10,
    },
    migrations: {
      tableName: 'knex_migrations',
      directory: path.resolve(__dirname, 'src', 'infra', 'knex', 'migrations'),
      loadExtensions: [extension],
      extension: extension,
    },
    seeds: {
      loadExtensions: ['.ts'],
    },
    timezone: 'UTC',
    useNullAsDefault: true,
    onUpdateTrigger: (table: string) => `
    CREATE TRIGGER ${table}_updated_at
    BEFORE UPDATE ON ${table}
    FOR EACH ROW
    EXECUTE PROCEDURE on_update_timestamp();
    `,
  },
};

const knexConfig = database['development'] as knex.Config;
module.exports = knexConfig;
```

basically my migrations files are in dirotiro src / infra / migrations

but my file is in src / config / knexfile.ts

i have this:

> directory: path.resolve(__dirname, 'src', 'infra', 'knex',
> 'migrations'),

but this dont work because my file is on folder: src/config not in base folder: ./

Answer (score 0):

`path` will understand the relative path when you try to resolve:

```js
directory: path.resolve(__dirname, '../infra/knex/migrations')
```